# While overriding method then facing issue

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface

While overriding method then facing an issue:

```
public interface IProduct {
    public void sendMessage(Object object);
}


@Service
public class ProductManagere implements IProduct{

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Product product) {
        // Added logic
    }
}
```

But getting below exception:

> The method sendMessage(Product) of type ProductManagere must override or implement a supertype method

I don't understand why is throwing this exception. I expect product is the subtype of Object so it will not throw an exception.

Answer (score 9):

In Java, overriding doesn't allow the covariance of the parameter.
It is only possible for the return type.
Why ?
Because changing the type of the parameter of the method in the subclass is not designed to *override* a method but to *overload* it. And it is not your intention.

So either you have to keep `Object` as parameter in the subclass (probably not what you want to) or make the interface a generic interface such as :

```
public interface IProduct<T> {
    void sendMessage(T object);
}
```

And the subclass :

```
@Service
public class ProductManagere implements IProduct<Product>{

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Product product) {
        // Added logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time I notice "xx variance" in an answer, I have to automatically upvote. Its in the genes of a person attending compiler construction lessons.

Comment: But it's worth saying *why* it doesn't accept a covariant parameter type.

Comment: @Andy Turner Right. Updated.

Comment: @davidxxx ok, but why does changing the parameter type make it overloading? I'm getting at the fact that `IProduct.sendMessage` says that it accepts any Object, so, in order to be Liskov-substitutable, `ProductManagere.sendMessage` must accept any Object too; but changing its parameter type to Product means that it can't handle anything that is not a Product (or null).

Comment: @Andy Turner  Sure it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed in Java. You have to use generics.

```
public interface IProduct<T> {
    public void sendMessage(T object);
}
```

And the service:

```
@Service
public class ProductManagere implements IProduct<Product> {

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Product product) {
        // Added logic
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, change the method in the interface to match the `Product`.

```
public void sendMessage(Product object);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your assumption were correct, what would happen in the following case:

```
IProduct prod = new ProductManager();
prod.sendMessage("String is a subclass of Object too");
```

Make the interface generic and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Must be exactly the same, because of LSP can be broken. However you can use generics to do the same with the type protection.

Comment: They needn't be exactly the same: LSP could be preserved if Java had been designed to allow contravariant parameter types. However, it wasn't, because the parameter type is significant in resolving method overloads.